# What's wrong with the counter decreasing?

Tags: jquery, arrays, counter

I'm removing item from the list and the counter decreases by the number of the elements before the one to be removed instead of just decreasing by one

Why is that ?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var count = 0;
            $("#clckToInsert").click(function () {
                var value = $('#misInput').val();
                var deleter = "<a href = #> X </a>";
                var li = '<li id = "item">' + value + deleter + '</li>'; 
                count++;
                $("#counter").html(count);
                $("#list").append(li);

                $('a').click(function () {
                    count--;
                    $(this).parent().remove();
                    $("#counter").html(count);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside of your `#clckToInsert` click handler, you are binding an additional click handler to every `a` every time it is fired:

```
$("#clckToInsert").click(function () {
    /* ... */
    $('a').click(function () {
```

So every time your `#clckToInsert` handler fires, every `a` on your page has an additional handler attached.  So every click on an `a` fire that many handlers, decreasing that number of times.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding the `count--` callback to any `<a>` element. This means that you have `n` handlers for any given link.

If you changed something the following it should be ok.

```
var $li = $(li)
$('#list').append($li)

$li.find('a').click
```

Comment: `value` is a string.  `string.find` will fail.

Comment: whoops, thought it was the new li.